# fontawesome - Icons appear only as rectangular shapes

Tags: css, font-awesome

as I wrote in the title when I use fontawesome, any icons appear only as rectangular shapes.

In this case I used fontawesome CDN-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

And I want to create angle right and angle left for slider which is position: relative

```
<a href="#" class="prev">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-5x"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="next">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-5x"></i>
                </a>
```

CSS -

```
.home .slider .prev {
position: absolute;
top: 425px;
left: 20px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #fff;
z-index: 200;}




.home .slider .next {
position: absolute;
top: 425px;
right: 20px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #fff;
z-index: 200;}
```

Does Anybody knows how to resolve that and what's the problem in this case so icons appear only as rectangular shapes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `href=""` part contains problems:

change it to :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

or even change `href=""` to `src=""` :

```
<link src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```